# Reading values of all text boxes of a screen

Tags: asp.net

In my application I have a master page, a web page that uses the master page, a panel and within the panel control I have several text box controls and a button to trigger the postback. I have written the following code to read the values entered in the text boxes. However, I am getting 0 count for the text box. Can you please let me know what is wrong in the code:

```
    // Function to read the entries of the text boxes.
    public ArrayList GetAllTextBoxes(Control parent)
    {
        ArrayList myActions = new ArrayList();
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {
            // Check and see if it's a textbox  
            if ((c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)))
            {
                // Since its a textbox read the text     
                myActions.Add(((TextBox)(c)).Text);
            }
            // Now we need to call itself (recursion) 
            if (c.HasControls())
            {
                GetAllTextBoxes(c);
            }
        }
        return myActions;
    }

    and this function is called like this on the click button function:

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList allActions = new ArrayList();
        ManageDef setStatus = new ManageDef();
        allActions = setStatus.GetAllTextBoxes(this);
    }
```

Comment: You can use `panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Select(txt=>txt.Text)` to find all `TextBoxes` in that `Panel` and select their text.

Comment: How are you defining the text boxes, are you instantiating them in code (i.e in the page load cycle), or defining them as controls in the view?

Answer (score 0):

You can write `GetAllTextBoxes()` like this:

```
// Function to read the entries of the text boxes.
public ArrayList GetAllTextBoxes(Control parent)
{
    ArrayList myActions = new ArrayList();
    if(parent.GetType() == typeof(Panel))//You may want to add other containers as well
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {
            // Check and see if it's a textbox  
            if ((c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)))
            {
                // Since its a textbox read the text     
                myActions.Add(((TextBox)(c)).Text);
            }
            // Now we need to call itself (recursion) 
            else if(c.GetType() == typeof(Panel))//Check for other containers if needed
            {
                if (c.HasControls())
                {
                    ArrayList myOtherActions = GetAllTextBoxes(c);
                    myActions.AddRange(myOtherActions);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return myActions;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList allActions = new ArrayList();
    ManageDef setStatus = new ManageDef();
    allActions = GetAllTextBoxes(Panel1);
    //Not sure if the buttton is inside the panel
    //allActions = GetAllTextBoxes(((Button)sender).Parent);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList allActions = new ArrayList();
        ManageDef setStatus = new ManageDef();
        allActions = setStatus.GetAllTextBoxes(this.parent);
    }
```

Comment: `this` is a `Page` object, so why should `this.Parent` help to find all TextBoxes on it's form?

Comment: so the button parent control.

Comment: `sender` is the `Button`, `this` refers to the class where the button-click handler is declared. I assume it's an ASP.NET page since OP mentioned: _"a web page that uses the master page, a panel and within the panel control I have several text box controls and a button to trigger the postback"_.

Comment: Hi Tim - Can you please let me know how to fix this problem.